# COUNT in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a html table where I want to show the `cht_name`, `count_hoh` and `count_members`. I can get the result for the count in `count_hoh` because I have the same field of `cht_id` on `household_tbl` and for the main table on `tbl_cht_members`. I'm have trouble in getting the count for `count_members` which is the table `tbl_household_members` which has the same field on `household_tbl` but doesn't have a field `cht_id` where I can directly get the count like the same on `count_hoh`. I am only linking them through `household_connector_id`.

```
SELECT cht_id as cht, name, 
       (SELECT household_connector_id as hoh,
               COUNT(*) 
          FROM household_tbl 
         WHERE cht_id = cht) as count_hoh,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM tbl_household_members 
         WHERE household_connector_id = hoh) as count_members
  FROM tbl_cht_members 
GROUP BY cht_id
```

Comment: you could explain your problem better by drawing some diagram of tables https://www.draw.io/ or post the schema of relevant tables

Answer (score 0):

try this wild guess ;)

```
SELECT 
    tbl_cht_members.cht_id as cht, tbl_cht_members.name,
    COUNT(household_tbl.cht_id) AS count_hoh,
    COUNT(tbl_household_members.household_connector_id) AS count_members
FROM
    tbl_cht_members LEFT JOIN household_tbl 
        ON tbl_cht_members.cht_id = household_tbl.cht_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_household_members
        ON household_tbl.household_connector_id = tbl_household_members.household_connector_id
```

You probably will have fix some field/table names and/or use `DISTINCT` but the concept will work IMO

Answer (score 0):

Since households already has a proper relationship, you could join it and group by the relationship (cht_id) and get your count for that.

But since the members table has a second degree relationship and you want another summation, you'd have to 'pre-aggregate' it and expose the relationship via your relating table (household_tbl).

```
     SELECT cht_id as cht, 
            name, 
            count(*) as households_cnt,
            members.cnt as member_cnt
       FROM tbl_cht_members cht
  LEFT JOIN household_tbl households  
         ON households.cht_id = cht.cht_id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT ht.cht_id, count(*) as cnt
               FROM tbl_household_members thm 
               JOIN household_tbl ht 
                 ON thm.household_connector_id = ht.household_connector_id
              GROUP BY thm.cht_id) members
         ON members.cht_id = cht.cht_id
   GROUP BY cht.cht_id, name, members.cnt
```

On a separate note: it really helps to organize the naming of your tables. You have "tbl" as both a pre and post fix - very confusing.  In fact, I'd probably leave it completely out.